# Same codeigniter application, different performances on different directories under apache2

Tags: php, performance, apache, codeigniter

I have a Codeigniter 2.2 application running on a linux server (ubuntu server 14.04) and I tried to copy it under another path and change Apache virtual host to point to the new directory, same configuration for everything else.

Under the first directory (/home/user1/apps/phpapp) performances are nice and smooth, but if I move it to a new directory by CPing it (let's say /home/user2/apps/phpapp) performances are strongly deteriorated.

On the virtual host configuration the only thing I changed was the document directory path, nothing else.

Any obvious reason for this to happen under Apache2?

Thanks in advance

Comment: i don't see how it can affect performance, but have you change the base url in the config file of your second app ?

Comment: of course I did. I swear the only change is the location where the application resides. I cannot find an explanation to this.